# Android mobile chip architectures different in different countries?

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, cpu, android

I have an android app that uses c libraries and is compiled for x86, armeabi and armeabi-v7a architectures.

I have noticed this recently, it seems as though some phone's will work in one country however it seems app users in Germany, Korea, Italy and Australia are having UnsatisfiedLinkErrors, specifically when using opencv ..

I've included the use of opencv through

```
static {

    System.loadLibrary("somecompiledlibname");

}
```

Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:()

So my questions are:

1) Are architectures different in different countries ?

2) How can I work around this ?

Comment: Reading [this](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html) there is nothing to that gives away about architectures in different countries, rather more than likely, the runtime is missing a library - *UnsatisfiedLinkErrors* is the problem here, are you bundling the library with the app? You may have to dig deeper, find out what models they are, and look them up, find out what is the base android version that comes with it. Could be also, the ROM may not have the native libraries compiled with hard floating points....

Comment: Do you load OpenCV native libraries implicitly? This won't work for Android API below 19 (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36950617).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Architectures differ between phones.  A given CPU uses the same architecture everywhere in the world.  x86 would be an Intel (or AMD) PC processor, sometimes used for tablets but fairly rarely.  ARM is a completely different type of chip, and used by almost every mobile device in the world.  ARMv7 is a more modern version of ARM, but won't work for older CPUs.  You're best off supporting all of them, although almost everything really will be ARMv7 these days.

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it address questions systematically

Answer (score 0):

You may call any OpenCV objects and functions, including object constructors only after OpenCV initialization. When OpenCV is initialized correctly onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS) is called.

Try the same as here:

```
static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        //..
    }
}
```